# shapeless - derive Selector of type constructor HList from base HList

Tags: scala, shapeless

I have a `Country` enum and an HList that is a **subset** of enum values:

```
import shapeless._
import iops.hlist.{Comapped, Selector}

sealed trait Country
case object US extends Country
case object DE extends Country
case object CA extends Country
...

val countries = US :: DE :: HNil
```

I have a `Price` class and `PriceTable` as below:

```
case class Price[C <: Country](value: Double)

class PricesTable[CountryList <: HList, PriceList <: HList](prices: PriceList)
  (implicit comapped: Comapped.Aux[PriceList, Price, CountryList]) {

def priceFor[C <: Country](implicit selector: Selector[CountryList, C]: Price[C] = 
  prices.select[Price[C]]
} 

val pricesTable = new PricesTable(Price[US.type](20) :: Price[DE.type](25) :: HNil)
```

The `priceFor` statement does not compile since a `Selector[PriceList, Price[C]]` is not in scope.

The code calling `priceFor` only has access to a `Selector[CountryList, C]` but not a `Selector[PriceList, Price[C]]` given that `CountryList =:= countries.type`.

Is there a way to derive a `Selector[PriceList, Price[C]]` from a `Selector[CountryList, C]` given that `Comapped.Aux[PriceList, Price, CountryList]` proves the relationship?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to achieve is to get the price of a given country type, since `Country` is a type parameter of `Price`, how about:

```
class PricesTable[PriceList <: HList](prices: PriceList)(implicit lubC: LUBConstraint[PriceList, Price[_]]) {
  def priceFor[C <: Country](implicit selector: Selector[PriceList, Price[C]]): Price[C] =
    prices.select[Price[C]]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. 

The code calling `priceFor` does not have a `Selector[PriceList, Price[C]]` in scope but only a `Selector[CountryList, C]`. Hence the need to derive one from the other.